# Google says my site has malware but nothing comes up in Webmaster Tools

Tags: google, google-search-console, malware, virus, modx

A few days ago my site was infected with Malware. I've sinced removed it and all is well. However, logging into the back end of my CMS I get the malware warning again.

I've followed the instructions which incdicates you can request a review of the site in Webmaster Tools. However, WM Tools says the site is free of malware.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of Googles block?

Comment: Which CMS are you using, and can you be more specific about the Malware warning you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is request a [Malware Review](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168328) which is not the same as a usual reconsideration request as it is handled by an entire different team. You do this from the Webmaster Tools.

Google explains all the steps in the process [here](http://www.google.com/webmasters/hacked/). If all you are missing is the Review, see [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168328).

Answer (score 0):

Google has a formal process for considering removing manual actions taken against sites in violation of its guidelines.

You can submit a "Request reconsideration" with Google:
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35843

This video may help explain the process as well:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=cA5I3HHApYk#!